# Deploying an asp.net project tthat was upgraded to .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I recently upgraded asp.net (framework 2.0) project to put at a new framework; 4.0. Do I have to deploy the entire site again to capture that it is pointing to new framework or are there specific files I need to depoly instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can just change the target framework in web.config, I would suggest rebuilding/redeploying once you have made the change.

> `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">`

Comment: Yes I saw that you could get away with just editing the web.config, but something made feel as though it would be best to rebuild/redeploy the site  as well. Thanks.